# Oracle query for merging multiple rows groupped by id and ordered by date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, union-all

I need help for writing view for this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/968d8/1). For now data looks like:

```
SERIALNUMBER | INSERTDATE           | PARAM1 | PARAM2 | PARAM3 | PARAM4 | PARAM5
3456         | 2017-11-15T12:00:54Z | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |  17
3456         | 2017-11-15T12:01:03Z | (null) | (null) |    2   | (null) | (null)
3456         | 2017-11-15T12:07:16Z | (null) | (null) | (null) |    7   | (null)
3456         | 2017-11-15T12:08:08Z | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |  19
3456         | 2017-11-15T12:11:32Z |   abc  | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null)
12           | 2017-11-15T12:00:50Z | (null) |    4   | (null) | (null) | (null)
12           | 2017-11-15T12:01:03Z | (null) |    7   | (null) | (null) | (null)
12           | 2017-11-15T12:07:03Z | (null) | (null) | (null) |   te   | (null)
```

The result which I want to receive is data groupped by serialnumber when if there are more columns with not null data groupping should pick newest:

```
SERIALNUMBER | INSERTDATE           | PARAM1 | PARAM2 | PARAM3 | PARAM4 | PARAM5
3456         | 2017-11-15T12:00:54Z |   abc  | (null) |    2   |    7   |  19
12           | 2017-11-15T12:00:50Z | (null) |    7   | (null) |   te   | (null)
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: What's with INSERTDATE in the output though? You are selecting the oldest date, not the newest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the exact rule for this, so I'm guessing you want the maximum value.  If so, this is a simple aggregation:

```
select serialnumber, min(InsertDate) as InsertDate,
       max(Param1) as Param1,
       max(Param2) as Param2,
       max(Param3) as Param3,
       max(Param4) as Param4,
       max(Param5) as Param5
from sample
group by serialnumber
order by InsertDate desc;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/968d8/12) is the SQL Fiddle.

I see, the OP does specify that the newest non-NULL value is to be chosen.

In that case:

```
select serialnumber, min(InsertDate) as InsertDate,
       max(Param1) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(Param1, 1, 2), InsertDate desc) as Param1,
       max(Param2) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(Param2, 1, 2), InsertDate desc) as Param2,
       max(Param3) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(Param3, 1, 2), InsertDate desc) as Param3,
       max(Param4) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(Param4, 1, 2), InsertDate desc) as Param4,
       max(Param5) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(Param5, 1, 2), InsertDate desc) as Param5
from sample
group by serialnumber
order by InsertDate desc;
```

And the corresponding [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/968d8/35).

Comment: Second solution is what I was looking for. Thanks!